# Changing APP_OPTIM in Application.mk causes full rebuild

Tags: android, build, android-ndk, compiler-optimization

I'm guessing that either Eclipse or the NDK build system are not using separate folders for compiler output regarding debug vs release builds, but for whatever reason it's making switching back and forth for debugging painfully slow since it's doing a full rebuild each time. Is there a remedy for this (bad) behavior?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that can cause this to occur:

1) If your change your Application.mk file the make system triggers a full rebuild.  I'm not sure if this is a standard of gnu make or related to how android is using make.

Solution:
Use two separate make files for release vs debug to prevent full rebuilds.

---

2) The output folder for your object files for release and debug are colliding.

`**Note:** This is not an issue with V9 of the NDK.  I was seeing this behavior with V8* NDK V9 seems to always us the APP_OPTIM when determining an output object folder.`

This has to do with the ndk_build parameter `NDK_DEBUG`.

When you invoke ndk_build without the `NDK_DEBUG=0|1` it will inspect the AndroidManifest.xml of your project.  If the android:debuggable flag is present it will set `NDK_DEBUG=1` if true or `NDK_DEBUG=0` if false. if debuggable is true the folder is `local/*abi*/objs`. If it is false the folder is `local/*abi*/objc-debug`.

The solution is the remove the debuggable flag from your manifest (this isn't needed if you are targeting SDK r8 or higher).  Next specify the `NDK_DEBUG=1` flag for your debug invocation of ndk_build, if you want to debug naive code.

---

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that ndk-build marks **Application.mk** as prerequisite for everything. It cannot know that only `NDK_DEBUG` changed.

You can safely provide `NDK_DEBUG` argument on command line. In Eclipse, you can create two separate build configurations, and switching will be one click.